# Topic in Mapping

Tags: analysis

Prove that for any mapping f, for any set A, for any x we have $x\in f^{-1}[A]$ iff $x\in D_f$ and $f(x) \in A$. I understand that in order for $x$ to be in the inverse image of the set A it must be true that $x$ is in the domain of the main function $f$ and that and that its image or in this case the function value f(x) is in A. How to setup a formal proof for this? Thanks!

Comment: You must require that $A \subset \mathrm{img}(f)$.

Comment: For a formal proof, you need the exact definition of the inverse image of a set.

Comment: @SeanRoberson There's no reason to  require that that I can see...

Comment: ??? What  you say you need to prove looks to me like the  _definition_ of $f^{-1}[A]$. How was that defined here, precisely?